# subprocess.Popen not working for reg query command

Tags: python, subprocess, registry

When i try to query a registry value (REG QUERY HKU /v "VBAWarnings" /s) popen() in python, I am getting 0 matches

```
import subprocess
command = 'REG QUERY HKU /v "VBAWarnings" /s'
output,error = subprocess.Popen(command,universal_newlines=True,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
```

If i print the output it is giving output as 0 matches

```
print output

End of search: 0 match(es) found.
```

But the the same command is giving a match while executing on the command prompt

Output:

```
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-2149410145-3230408028-977776915-
500\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Word\Security

    VBAWarnings    REG_DWORD    0x1

End of search: 1 match(es) found.
```

Comment: Can you try something like `proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
print proc.communicate()`

Comment: What does the command print out when executed from command prompt? Also, have you also checked `error` (as the command output might be there)?

Comment: Why not use [**`winreg`**](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/winreg.html)?

Comment: @Varad Still not working, I think it is not the problem with the params, the command string might be problem, because the same is working in command prompt

Comment: @PeterWood I want to execute the command in remote machine without python

Comment: @CristiFati have updated the output

Comment: So the key is there.... What I suspect is the 32/64 bit mismatch... According to [\[SS64\]: Reg.exe](https://ss64.com/nt/reg.html), _reg_ supports `/reg:32` and `/reg:64` arguments. A quick search didn't reveal that info on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/default.aspx), and the arguments aren't present on my current computer (!!! _XP_ !!!). Could you check (`reg query /?`) if your _reg_ utility supports them, and if yes add them (one at a time) to `command`?

Comment: @CristiFati The command is working fine on cmd prompt, it is not working with Popen

Comment: So, either of `REG QUERY HKU /v "VBAWarnings" /s /reg:32`, `REG QUERY HKU /v "VBAWarnings" /s /reg:64` doesn't work from _Python_? I assume that the _Win_ user that you run _Python_ with is the same one that you run the _cmd_ window where you (directly) run the _reg_ command from (as a `HKU` key is involved).

Comment: @CristiFati Thank you, Python was not running under Admin but cmd prompt was run as Admin.